# Create new line based on each regex match in python

Tags: python, regex

I have an input file that contains data formatted as follows:

a; b, c| derp derp "X1234567, Y1234567, Z1234567" derp derp a; b, c|

I would like to use Python to parse that into multiple lines for each item that occurs between double quotes.

The output for the above example would be:

a; b, c| derp derp X1234567 derp derp a; b, c|

a; b, c| derp derp Y1234567 derp derp a; b, c|

a; b, c| derp derp Z1234567 derp derp a; b, c|

So far I have something like this:

```
import re
prefix = re.compile ('^(.*?)"')
pattern = re.compile('\"(.*?)([A-Z]{1}[0-9]{7})(.*?)\"')
suffix = re.compile ('"(.*?)$')
for i, line in enumerate(open('myFile.txt')):
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, line):
        print prefix, match.group(), suffix
```

But it only seems to return the first match of each of the contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation it's actually a lot more work (in my opinion) to use regex rather than simple string and list manipulations.  I would just do it as such:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

with open('myFile.txt','r') as f:
    lines = readlines(f)

for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    start = line.find('"')
    end = line.find('"',start+1)
    data = line[start+1:end].split(',')
    data = [x.strip() for x in data]
    for x in data:
        print line[:start],x,line[end+1:]
```

Here's what I found after taking a look at the code you posted:

- You're actually printing `SRE_Pattern` objects for `prefix` and `suffix` in the print line.  You should record matches for prefix and suffix on every iteration of the outer for loop.
- Calling `match.group()` will return the entire match, not just what's in parentheses.  I think you want `match.group(1)` in most cases.
- Having `pattern` defined like that only matches one string because it searches sequentially through the lines for a starting quotation mark followed by the rest of the pattern.  Therefore it gets to the index for the first quotation mark, checks once for a pattern, finds `X1234567` then moves on.
- I'm not sure why you have backslashes before the quotation marks in `pattern`, as I don't think those are special characters.
- In your `suffix`, it will match the first quotation mark not the second, and thus `suffix` will include the stuff between the quotation marks.
- The print statement will insert spaces between items if you use commas, so you should concatenate them using `+` instead.

And finally here is what I ended up with for regex:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

prefix = re.compile('^(.*?)"')
quotes = re.compile('".*?(.*).*?"')
pattern = re.compile('[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{7}')
suffix = re.compile('".*"(.*?)$')
    
for (i,line) in enumerate(open('myfile.txt')):
    pre = prefix.search(line).group(1)
    data = quotes.search(line).group(1)
    suf = suffix.search(line).group(1)
    for match in re.finditer(pattern,data):
        print pre+match.group(0)+suf
```

Hope this helps, any questions please ask.  Regex is a tricky beast at the best of times.